# SXA Google Analytics tracking enable

Tags: sxa

I am trying to add Google analytics script code by using SXA OOB feature. I found that template is available at the path `/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Analytics/Rendering Parameters/Google Analytics`

Any inputs on how to enable Google Analytics tracking in SXA?

Comment: You can use the ootb component and add the GA key.. what is your actual question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google Analytics component should be added to the `Metadata` partial design, which is included by default in sites.

To add the component, in Experience Editor go to the Metadata partial design:

[image: Selecting the Metadata Partial Design]

This will give you a view of the current metadata renderings you have selected for your site, and allow you to drag metadata components into the `<head>` or `<body>` tags of your site's page layout.

The Google Analytics component can be found in the toolbox under Analytics:

[image: Google Analytics component]

Drag this into the `<head>` section of the page. When you add this, the rendering will inform you that you must add a key for this to work:

[image: The Google Analytics component before a key is added]

To add the key, this is set as a rendering parameter on the component, under the Tracking heading:

[image: Adding the tracking key to the component properties]

Once that's done you can save the partial design and your site should start outputting the tracking code.

Comment: Thank you,, This is what i am looking for.